# using python to get data from an api into power bi

Tags: python, api, python-requests, powerbi

I am trying to import some data into a powerbi workbook through a basic python function to retrieve data using the 'requests' package into a pandas df then into power bi. however, as soon as power bi executes the script the following error is returned

[image]

this error isn't present if i load only one df...

Comment: Do you **have** to use the python built-in to PBI? I would avoid if at all possible

Comment: do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: thats about all i can say without some code to look at.